# Finding the position of a substring in a larger string

Tags: c, string, function, for-loop, substring

I have created a function that should find the numerical position of the first character of a substring in a larger string. I am having some problems with the output and I am not too sure why. These problems include -1 being returned every single time instead of the integer position of the substring. I have debugged and cannot trace where the function goes wrong.

This is how the function should perform: If my string is "The dog was fast" and I am searching for the substring "dog", the function should return 4. Thanks to chqrlie for help with the loop.

Here is the function:

```
int findSubString(char original[], char toFind[]) {

    size_t i, j;
    int originalLength = 0;
    int toFindLength = 0;

    originalLength = strlen(original) + 1;
    toFindLength = strlen(toFind) + 1;

    for (i = 0; i < toFindLength + 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < originalLength + 1; j++) {
            if (toFind[j] == '\0') {
                return i;
            }
            if (original[i + j] != toFind[j]) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (original[i] == '\0') {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

The function parameters cannot be modified, this is a requirement. Any help appreciated!

Comment: "I am having some problems". What problems? Please be specific. And have you used a debugger to trace the execution of your program? How about basic debug print statements? Any kind of debugging at all?

Comment: `j` refers to `original` but is used in `toFind`. You should consider swapping `toFindLength` and `originalLength` in the `for` loops.

Comment: @kaylum Sorry, I edited to hopefully give more insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These statements inside the loops

```
       if (toFind[j] == '\0') {
            return i;
        }
```

results in undefined behavior because the string `toFind` can be shorter than the string `original`.

The same is valid for this loop

```
        if (original[i + j] != toFind[j]) {
            break;
        }
```

because `i + j` can be greater than the length of the string `original`.

And there is no need to scan all characters of the string `original` if you are going to find a substring inside it.

Also you should check whether the length of the string `original` is not less than the length of the string `toFind`.

If you want to find only the first character of the string `toFind` in the string `original` it is enough to use standard C function `strchr`. If you want to find the whole string `toFind` in the string `original` then you could use another C standard function `strstr`.

If you want to write the function yourself to find a string in other string then it can look for example the following way

I declared the function like

```
long long int findSubString( const char original[], const char toFind[] );
```

however you can write its declaration as you like for example like

```
int findSubString( char original[], char toFind[] );
```

But in this case you should declare function local variable `success` like

```
int success = -1;
```

and output the result using format specifier `"%d"` instead of `"%lld"`.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>

long long int findSubString( const char original[], const char toFind[] )
{
    size_t n = strlen( original );
    size_t m = strlen( toFind );

    long long int success = -1;

    if ( !( n < m ) )
    {
        n = n - m + 1;

        for ( size_t i = 0; success == -1 && i < n; i++ )
        {
            size_t j = 0;
            while ( j < m && original[i+j] == toFind[j] ) j++;

            if ( j == m ) success = i;
        }
    }

    return success;
}

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "%lld\n", findSubString( "The dog was fast", "dog" ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
4
```

Comment: Okay, so even with this new function, my output is still no matter what -1. Does it make a difference that instead of my input being hard coded like it is in your example, I get my original string from an array and specify where in the array it is coming from, and the substring just from the user. Could this be somehow messing it up?

Comment: @Monty For example if you enter a string using standard C function fgets then it appends the new line character to the entered string. You should remove it.

Comment: @Monty Another problem can be that a string is not zero-terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Your loops are reversed. The outer loop should walk positions from zero to `originalLength`, inclusive; the nested loop should walk positions from zero to `toFindLength`, inclusive.

Both `originalLength` and `toFindLength` should be set to values returned by `strlen`, not `strlen` plus one, because null terminator position is not a good start.

Finally, you are returning `-1` from inside the outer loop. This is too early - you should be returning `-1` only after you are done with the outer loop as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop counter tests are incorrect: wrong upper limit and the limits are off by one.  Note that the tests are actually not necessary as you exit both loops when hitting the `'\0'` terminators.

Here is a simpler version:

```
int findSubString(const char *original, const char *toFind) {
    for (size_t i = 0;; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0;; j++) {
            if (toFind[j] == '\0') {
                return i;
            }
            if (original[i + j] != toFind[j]) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (original[i] == '\0') {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

There is a small advantage at computing the string lengths to reduce the number of comparisons in pathological cases such as `findSubString("aaaaaaaaaaa", "aaaaaaaaaaaa");`

```
int findSubString(const char *original, const char *toFind) {
    size_t originalLength = strlen(original);
    size_t toFindLength = strlen(toFind);

    if (toFindLength <= originalLength) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i <= originalLength - toFindLength; i++) {
            for (size_t j = 0;; j++) {
                if (toFind[j] == '\0') {
                    return i;
                }
                if (original[i + j] != toFind[j]) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```